# How to put a vertical bar with simple spaces between sentences without French spacing

Tags: frenchspacing

I am typesetting Biblical quotations in paragraphs following the convention of the French Segond 21: where there is a verse break inside a paragraph, there is a light gray vertical bar, with the verse numbers at the end of the quotation (if it was an actually Bible, they would be at the margins).

Now, I am using double spacing between sentences, and it becomes ugly because the double spacing ends up preceding the vertical bar.

Is there a way of turning off the double spacing in a specific paragraph or even sentence break?

Comment: For readers not (yet) familiar with the "French Segond 21" typesetting convention, would it be possible to post a screenshot of a paragraph that implements this convention?